# VMWare image not starting -> Strange error

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

Since 2 days I'm trying to start my .vmx image. A week ago, everything worked fine but now I'm getting a bootloop and this strange error before automatic reboot of the image:

> exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action

Is anyone out here who has an idea what could be wrong?

I'm using an Ubuntu 18.04 TLS with VMWare Workstation Pro 15.

What I already did:

- Restart of the computer
- Re-install of VMWare Workstation for Linux
- Chown the sources to the current user
- Used Google for 2 days to find the problem

Answer (score 1):

This message means an unrecoverable read error on the disk, which could be the
physical or virtual one.

You should run `fsck` on both disks, which might clear up the error.

If you cannot boot, use a live CD or a bootable USB.
You may use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) for
creating the bootable USB.

If the error is on the physical disk, it might need replacement.